# Launching processing when opening / closing QGIS project

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to automatically run any processing models when you open or close a QGIS project? (or maybe a layer?)

I have a model that I run to update multiple fields in multiple shapefile layers, and I would like it to run each time the project is opened and/or closed so that it's not forgotten.

Answer (score 5):

In your project properties, you can define **Python macros**.

You have 3 macros:

1. one when the project opens
2. one when the project is saved
3. one when the project is closed

[image]

Comment: Thanks - looks like the solution I was looking for.  Now if I only knew how to write the code to run the model file...